# Android sdk on Ubuntu 32bit

Tags: android, 15.10, adb, android-sdk

I have some issues in running android sdk(ADB) on ubuntu 32-bit. I downloaded and updated sdk on ubuntu 14.02 64-bit, and now reusing it on ubuntu 15.10 32-bit. But when i try `./adb devices` on terminal, i get this error:

```
bash: ./adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I just want to ask that, **is Android SDK work on ubuntu 32-bit?**

Comment: Yes; there is a 32-bit version to download and install.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist: can you give me that link?

Comment: Yes, please provide this 32 bit version link. It seems they only have a 64 bit version available for download now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312171/how-to-develop-for-android-on-a-32-bit-linux

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally get it here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102096/5070449

1) Install 'adb' and 'fastboot' provided by the following third-party PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

2) Replace the copy of 'adb' and 'fastboot' provided by the official Android SDK with those installed from the above step:

```
cp /usr/bin/adb <path-to-your-adt-sdk-package>/sdk/platform-tools/adb
cp /usr/bin/fastboot <path-to-your-adt-sdk-package>/sdk/platformtools/fastboot
```

3) That it. Now run

```
<path-to-your-adt-sdk-package>/sdk/platform-tools/adb
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
```

Comment: In ubuntu, if you are trying to run ./adb from terminal and get Error: 

"error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0"

The above solution will also work for this problem.

Comment: there is a small typo in the latter command in second point, it is  

cp /usr/bin/fastboot <path-to-your-adt-sdk-package>/sdk/platform-tools/fastboot

Answer (score 6):

The platform tools now only consist tools for 64 bit architecture. To fix this issue, you need to download platform-tools r23.0.1 which are for 32 bit architecture which can be found at Google's repository [here](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip).
Once you download it, simply go to your `Sdk` folder and replace the content of `platform-tools` folder there with the content of downloaded `platform-tools` folder. It should work like a charm right away.

**NOTE**- You might want to backup previous platform-tools folder.

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196866

Comment: It best soluation...

Comment: @MahdiParsa which processor do you use?

Comment: Download this https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r23.0.1-linux.zip  repo and replace with Ubuntu nilarimogard/webupd8 adb and fastboot. because I user Ubuntu 32bit :)

Comment: @MahdiParsa Well I wanted to say that if you're using any `i` series processor then you might as well switch to a 64bit OS so you don't miss out on the newest SDKs

Comment: I am using ubuntu 32 bit and when followed above step .. still could not run adb. cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.

Answer (score 3):

**Normal Installation - Current (64bit only)**

Try freshly downloading and freshly install the [Android SDK package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other).  This is probably what you originally did on your x64 system.  On that install it configured it for your x64.  Performing the same steps should configure it for your 32bit Ubuntu installation.

**Archived SDK (I386)**

I checked the installation of the current sdk as provided by Google (`developer.android.com`).  Because there weren't any specifics referring to i386 or x64 architecture, I assumed the install would recognize the installation type and configure binaries accordingly.  I tested what I provided and it appears the official current download only works with x64.  The latest 32bit I could find (provided by Google) is an archive.  You can find it at [Android SDK Package (i386) - Older Release](http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html).

Comment: i install new sdk and update it. but still same error
~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools# ./adb
bash: ./adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @IBRARAHMAD After the install (which is simply extracting the download to a unique place).  Did you go to your extracted folder and run `./android`.  It's the `./android` command which will complete the install and setup.  After the install, then you'll have access to the tools... the sdk.  Be sure to have the extracted folder different from the previous install from the 64bit OS.  If you continue to have problems, I'll perform a clean install to  32 bit Ubuntu and add the formatted steps performed to my answer.

Comment: @IBRARAHMAD I updated my answer after testing an install on a 32bit ubuntu installation.

Comment: Such a disrespectful gesture from google. Can't believe they dropped support for huge part of developers